wrong introductoryEligibility when getting information from a sku with glassfy and capacitor
Glassfy Capacitor lib return GLASSFY_ELEGIBILITY.NON_ELEGIBLE for a SKU but click on purchase link show that introductory price is eligible
In the page showing products to buy I check the Eligibility of introductory reduction by doing that
  setSkuAnnualy(await Glassfy.skuWithId({ identifier: annualProduct }));
  if (skuAnnualy) {
     console.log(skuAnnualy.introductoryEligibility);
  }

And Glassfy return GLASSFY_ELEGIBILITY.NON_ELEGIBLE
but if i click on purchase button on an IOS device here is what I have
purchase summary
what I have done wrong?
the version of the glassfy-capacitor lib is "3.3.4"
